# bash prompt : how to display only the filename with PS1?

Tags: bash, sed, ps1

I am currently displaying the directory path and the git branch using `PS1`:

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

which is prompting :

```
john@myMac /Volumes/.../.../.../MyProject (master) $
```

but as my full path ( displayed with `\w\[\033[33m\]` is quite long, I would like to display only the filename...

```
john@myMac MyProject (master) $
```

there is no such option in `PS1`...  Is it possible ?

Thanks for feedback

Comment: See also the `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\W` instead of `\w`:

```
export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\W\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

As per `man bash`:

```
\w     the  current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde 
       (uses the value of the PROMPT_DIRTRIM variable)
\W     the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
```

Answer (score 0):

Cut the $PWD:

```
export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]${PWD##*/}\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```